# Did I commit kufr

Tags: kufr

I was thinking about something and then I got angry, and I accidentally clicked on this islamic video and then I said in my head "nobody gives a f" when I was angry. Then I realized what I did and got even more angry and in my head I said "Now I probably lost my f*ing religion". Does this mean I committed kufr I was angry at that time and forgot. I don't think it was waswasa so did I lose my religion?

Answer (score -1):

If you did not do any actions or face movement it dosent count but you should look up how to fight waswas